# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install

Tags: partitioning, 14.04, system-installation, hard-drive

I tried to install the new Ubuntu that I downloaded from the official website. I burned it to a DVD and when everything loads up I get as far as the connect to wifi and that has a green check mark by it, but the Drive space says I need at least 6.4 GB of hard drive with a gray X next to it. I bought a new internal hard drive and tried the install on that and it still says the same thing. The disc is rewritable and hard drives are 160GB and the new hard drive is 500GB 5400 rpm. The continue button does not light up as it is not recognizing. I have sufficient hard drive space.

What am I doing wrong. Has anyone else come across this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You have to create swap partition about 100MB. Have you done it ?

Comment: No,how do you do that?

Comment: How do I get to that screen? My hard drive is empty. Do I do it from the installation DVD?

Comment: I insert the disc and then it asks me if I want to install Ubuntu or try it out. I click install ubuntu then it ask me what language. I pick english then it goes to the next screen. In the next screen it has a grey x with needing to have 6.4  GB hard space. It gives me no option to partition.

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing Ubuntu, create a 1024MB swap partition, like be made in this photo : http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_MfwRx_4ERx8/Sa6_NX-VJ2I/AAAAAAAAAxI/m5gNeh84icA/s400/ubuntu-partition-9.jpg

Then it will work.

Comment: Do I use Gparted and partition the disc? That is the only device that Gparted is seeing.